# A problem with the listofitems package

Tags: comma-separated-list, listofitems

Using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10 I've run into a problem with `listofitmes`. In the code shown:

```
    % arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{listofitems}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    
    \newenvironment{RuneQuoteDebug}[1]{
      \begin{quote}
        \setsepchar{,}
        \readlist\args{#1}
        number of items = \argslen\par
        \showitems\args\par
        \foreachitem\list\in\args{
          Top level list item number \listcnt{}: \list\par
          \readlist\chars\list
          \foreachitem\cc\in\chars{
            Second level list item number \cccnt{}: \cc\par
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cc}{\string 0}}
              {}
              {\cc}
          }
        }
      }{
      \end{quote}
    }
    
    \def\li{46,69,55}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{RuneQuoteDebug}{\li}\end{RuneQuoteDebug}
    \begin{RuneQuoteDebug}{0,\li}\end{RuneQuoteDebug}
    \begin{RuneQuoteDebug}{\li,\li}\end{RuneQuoteDebug}
    \end{document}
```

I run the same user-defined environment three times. The first time with a single time in the list, The second time with two items, a placeholder, and the list. A lastly with two instances of the test item. I originally expected no problems until I saw problems in the resulting .pdf output. Next, I wrote the debug version of `RuneQuoteDebug`. This uncovered the difference when the list contained one item compared to more than one item. I do not know if the difference is by design and I admit that it isn't all that hard to program around. On the chance that it is something that I'm doing wrong, I'm looking for corrections. Since there are always things that can be improved, I'd certainly take any suggestions to heart. As a result, I'd like code that works the same regardless of the number of items passed to the environment.

**NOTE**: based on something I said above I just tested another approach. It seems that this behavior is *intended* and I just failed to pick up on what it would take to handle the single item case. As I should have inferred from some of the example code, items may be partitioned by using curly braces. This means that instead of using a place-holder (that must be allowed for) a simple `{{\li}}` will suffice. As the great Emily LaTilla would say "*Never mind.*" I suppose if you want I'd hardly complain about improvements…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is a feature. A lone control-sequence comprising the list is *presumed* to be a `\def` of the actual desired list, so the control-sequence  is once-expanded before the list is read.

For a single level parsing, a solution might be to add `\empty` to the end of your list, so that a lone `\li` is not pre-expanded.  However, your task performs nested parsings.  So what I recommend here instead is to add a blank entry to the end of your list by adding a comma separator `,`.  Then also employ the `\ignoreemptyitems` declaration, so that the final blank entry is ignored.

```
    % arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
    \documentclass{article}
%    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{listofitems}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    
    \newenvironment{RuneQuoteDebug}[1]{
      \begin{quote}
        \setsepchar{,}
        \ignoreemptyitems
        \readlist\args{#1}
        number of items = \argslen\par
        \showitems\args\par
        \foreachitem\list\in\args{
          Top level list item number \listcnt{}: \list\par
          \readlist\chars\list
          \foreachitem\cc\in\chars{
            Second level list item number \cccnt{}: \cc\par
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cc}{\string 0}}
              {}
              {\cc}
          }
        }
      }{
      \end{quote}
    }
    
    \def\li{46,69,55}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{RuneQuoteDebug}{\li,}\end{RuneQuoteDebug}
    \begin{RuneQuoteDebug}{0,\li}\end{RuneQuoteDebug}
    \begin{RuneQuoteDebug}{\li,\li}\end{RuneQuoteDebug}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will test (this time thoroughly) both and let you know!

Comment: Use of `\empty` leads to `! Package listofitems Error: Empty list ignored, nothing to do.`. The trailing comma is both the shortest and cleanest solution so far.

Comment: @hsmyers I did not mean `\readlist{\empty}`, nor `\readlist{\li,\empty}`, but rather `\readlist{\li\empty}`, in order to prevent `\li` from being expanded once prior to the list read.

Comment: Ah! That way there is no error, but the list seems irreducible level to level.

Comment: @hsmyers Correct.  The `\empty` approach only works if you are not nesting the list reads.  For the nested list reads, the approach shown in my MWE is what I recommend.

Comment: @hsmyers In the environment definition, you could just do `...\readlist\args{#1,}...` to automatically add that blank list.